# Finding the longest prefix among words in a string separated by spaces (Swift)

Tags: performance, swift

Solving the problem

> Write a function that accepts a string of words with a similar prefix,
> separated by spaces, and returns the longest substring that prefixes
> all words. Sample input and output
>
> The string “swift switch swill swim” should return “swi”. The string
> “flip flap flop” should return “fl”.

I have

```
import Foundation

func longestPrefix(of string: String) -> String {
    var longestPrefix = ""
    var prefixBeingChecked = ""
    
    let wordArray = string.components(separatedBy: " ")
    
    var firstWord = wordArray[0]
    
    for character in firstWord {
        prefixBeingChecked += String(character)
        
        for word in wordArray {
            if !word.hasPrefix(prefixBeingChecked) {
                return longestPrefix
            }
        }
        
        longestPrefix = prefixBeingChecked
    }
    
    return longestPrefix
}

print(longestPrefix(of: "swift switch swill swim"))
```

But I'm not sure how I might improve on the quadratic time complexity. What would be a good way to improve performance?

Comment: While it's great that a review enabled you to improve your code, please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers. Doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review, as it unfortunately invalidates the existing review(s). This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question, so I rolled your changes back to the previous version. Please see see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)* for ways to announce your new code.

Comment: Oops, I only did since I couldn't format multi-line code in a comment. Noted.

Comment: Btw, your new method (sorting by string length) does not work, try it with the input string `"abc abxx abcdefg"`. Also sorting requires O(n*log(n)) operations, which is worse than a single traversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some remarks:

```
let wordArray = string.components(separatedBy: " ")
```

produces an array of strings. A slightly more memory-efficient method is

```
let wordArray = string.split(separator: " ")
```

which produces an array of `Substring`s which share the character storage with the original string.

The variable

```
var firstWord = wordArray[0]
```

is never mutated and should be defined as a constant with `let`. If we use `split(separator:)` then the array can be empty:

```
guard let firstWord = wordArray.first else {
    return ""
}
```

In the inner loop

```
for word in wordArray { ... }
```

it is not necessary to check against the first word in the list, so one can replace that by

```
for word in wordArray.dropFirst() { ... }
```

Is is not common practice in Swift to make the type part of the variable name, so I would replace `wordArray` by, e.g., `words`.

#### A more efficient algorithm

A more efficient solution has been described in  [Find the longest common starting substring in a set of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings/1917041#1917041) on Stack Overflow, see also [How to determine longest common prefix and suffix for array of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48449365/1187415) on Stack Overflow:

- Find the smallest and largest string in the array.
- Determine the common prefix of just those two strings.

The first part requires only a linear traversal of the array, plus the cost of the string comparisons.

There is a dedicated method `commonPrefix(with:)` for the second part.

This leads to the following implementation:

```
func longestCommonPrefix(of string: String) -> String {
    
    let words = string.split(separator: " ")
    guard let first = words.first else {
        return ""
    }

    var (minWord, maxWord) = (first, first)
    for word in words.dropFirst() {
        if word < minWord {
            minWord = word
        } else if word > maxWord {
            maxWord = word
        }
    }

    return minWord.commonPrefix(with: maxWord)
}
```